# resharper disable for c# .cs files

Tags: resharper

is it possible to only enable resharper for javascript and css files? I don't want it inspecting my c# files as it's driving me nuts with it's styling and and at times somewhat controversial recommendations. I haven't got time to set each individual setting, I'm just looking for a "don't inspect c# files" check box, if there isn't one I think my resharper trial will be officially over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to disable ReSharper for C#, try going to ReSharper | Options -> Code Inspection | Settings -> Edit Items to Skip and add a file mask to skip *.cs.

But better way would be to disable those ReSharper warnings that you don't like. To do this, click Alt-Enter on the suggestion that you don't like, go to Options submenu, select Configure inspection severity and then Do not show. This is for ReSharper 8.0, in 7.1 it should be pretty similar.